Number of lattice points on the hypotenuse in a right triangle

Say $A(0,y_1),B(0,0),C(x_1,0),E(x_1-n,y_1-k)$ all being lattice points. Also $n\leq x_1$ & $k\leq y_1$. We need a relation between n and k, where $n, k \in N$,  so that corresponding to every integral k we can check whether the x-coordinate is also integral. Applying similarity on $\triangle ADE$ and $\triangle EFC$, $\frac{k}{y_1-k}=\frac{x_1-n}{n}\implies x_1-\frac{kx_1}{y_1}=n$. So for $n\in N$, $$y_1|kx_1$$How should i proceed next? My goal is to find number of such $k$.

$\overline{AC}$ has equation $y = y_1 - \frac{y_1}{x_1}x$, which will be integral if and only if $x_1\mid xy_1$. Thus, if $d = \text{gcd}(x_1, y_1)$ and $q = \frac{x_1}d$, then the lattice points will be exactly those where $x$ is a multiple of $q$.
